# What does, "Cannot extract the mkspecs directory." when running `qbs setup-qt /usr/bin/qmake qt` mean?

Tags: qt, qmake, qbs

I am following this [tutorial](https://doc.qt.io/qbs/howtos.html#how-do-i-build-a-qt-based-project), and the first command

```
qbs setup-qt /usr/bin/qmake qt
```

returns this error:

```
Cannot extract the mkspecs directory.
```

What is this trying to tell me, and is this something I need to fix?

Answer (score 1):

This is a fatal error that means the Qt profile could not be set up. It should never happen if Qt is correctly installed. What kind of Qt is this? Does it come from the distribution? What is the output of qmake -query?

Comment: The Qt I am building against is not installed by the ubuntu repos. Instead, it sits in `/home/Programming/Qt/...` ; Perhaps informing of its proper location will fix my issue... Thanks. The output is this: `qmake: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake': No such file or directory` ... which is also interesting...

Comment: Ok, that means Qt is not properly installed then. There's nothing qbs can do about that.